# Unable to use 'diff' command using 'lambda-git' library in python (AWS Lambda)

Tags: python-3.x, git, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I imported git (lambda-git) library in AWS lambda(python 3.7). Im able to execute all the below commands.

```
git.exec_command("clone", "repo-url", "/tmp/repo")
new_repo_path = '/tmp/repo'
git.exec_command('init', cwd=new_repo_path) 
git.exec_command('branch', '-v', cwd=new_repo_path)
git.exec_command('fetch' , cwd=new_repo_path )
git.exec_command('checkout' , 'branch', cwd=new_repo_path )
```

But when I try to use the below command,

```
git.exec_command('diff','--name-only HEAD HEAD~1', cwd=new_repo_path)
```

Im getting the below error,

```
[ERROR] GitExecutionError: command=['git', 'diff', '--name-only HEAD HEAD~1'] returncode=255 stdout="b''" stderr="b'error: invalid option: --name-only HEAD HEAD~1\n'"
```

But when I try to run the same command(given below) as git cli I'm getting proper results

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
```

Is there anything I'm missing? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `'--name-only HEAD HEAD~1'` should probably be `'--name-only', 'HEAD', 'HEAD~1'`, i.e. separate arguments.

Comment: Worked !Thanks :)